# Adoptable storage prior to marshmallow?

Tags: adoptable-storage

As most people know, adoptable storage is a feature that allows users to use an SD card as internal storage, including the saving of apps (Similar to the app2sd system, which was removed in KitKat). Now, is there **any** way (Short of creating my own custom ROM/kernel) to utilise this feature on phones and tablets before Marshmallow?

Edit: I should clarify that I mean **anything** that *replicates the behaviour* of adoptable storage (so anything like editing `vold` file still counts, from the accepted answer, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I could find that matches OP's expectations and should work, requires rooted device ( not tested by me). This **only**  replicates *adoptable-storage* behaviour of Marshmallow to the extent it allows use of external SD to be used as internal SD for moving apps

**Sources:**

1. [Swap internal storage with the SD card in Android Lollipop and KitKat](https://www.skyneel.com/how-to-swap-internal-storage-with-the-sd-card-in-android-device)
2. [How to swap internal storage with the SD card in Android device](https://www.skyneel.com/how-to-swap-phone-storage-with-sd-card-in-android-device)

Both these are blogs by the same person but take  different approaches:

**Source 1** requires

- Xposed module [XInternalSD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinternalsd) :

> This module changes value (path to internal SD card) in some Android APIs which apps use. Control this path in module's settings. You can enable this module for all apps or only for specific apps. Also you can enable full access to external SD card (for KitKat+)

And

- WSM Tools app that can be downloaded from [Aptoide](http://m.aptoide.com/) - not available on Play Store

**Source 2** requires only Xposed module [XInternalSD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinternalsd)

**Approach**

- Swap internal storage with external SD using the XInternalSD module ( Common step for both methods)

[image]

- Using WSM Tools  choose apps which you want to move External SD or move all apps (*Source 1*)

*OR*

- Using a root explorer amend `vold.fstab`  to interchange `sdcard0` with `sdcard1` ( *Source 2*)

Comment: Nice. As I have now edited into the question, it doesn't have to be adoptable storage, just a situation where it's behaviour is replicated

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Actually this solution of switching to external SD brings a sense of  *Deja Vu* :)

Comment: Lol, we'll question why later :)